# TypeError when run

Tags: python

I am using pycharm 3.5 on Windows 7 
I get typeError when reach line 19 , unorderable types
Int()

```
Import random
guessTaken =0
print('hello what is your name') 

myName =input ()
number=random.randint(1,20)

print('well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20')

While guessTaken < 6:  
    print ('take a guess') 
    guess =input()
    guess=int(guess)

    guessTaken=guessTaken +1
    If guess <number:.  # this where the error occur!
        print('your guess is too low')
     If guess>number:
         print('guess is too high') 

     If guess==number:
         break
     If guess==number:

        guessTaken = str(guessTaken) 
        print('good job, ' + myName + ' you guess my number in ' + guessTaken +'guess')
      If guess !=number:
           number=str (number)
```

How to fix this and any other mistake seen  ??don't watch the formatting using a mobile phone

Comment: "don't watch the formatting using a mobile phone" - formatting is really important in Python, even more so than in other programming languages. If you can't format your code on your phone, you shouldn't be posting questions on your phone.

Comment: `number=str (number)` - why the heck?

Comment: @user2357112 The formatting is crap when viewed on a handheld device... regardless of whether it's actually fine or not...

Comment: 1. `While` with a capital `W`, same with `If` and `Import` 2. Multiple `guess == number` conditions.

Comment: All your `If`'s (which should be `if`'s) are not indented properly...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of your loop, you strangely convert `number` to a string.  You can't compare that to an integer.  Just remove that comparison and conversion from the bottom of your code.